# Is it possible to remove gnome-contacts in 14.04?

Tags: gnome, software-center, contacts

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04.01 after coming back from using Mint.  I'm cleaning up some of the software that comes installed that I don't need or want.  One of those applications is gnome-contacts.  I have no use for a contact app installed on my system as I use Google Contacts.  Is it possible to remove this?  I saw a mention in Ubuntu Software Center that this can cause problems if it is removed but this isn't definite.  Has anyone removed this with no problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using regular ubuntu with the unity desktop: yes, it is possible.

If you are using gnome-shell desktop instead of unity, you will run into dependency issues.

Go ahead and uninstall it if you are using just the regular "Ubuntu Desktop" and are not using the gnome desktop otherwise known as "Ubuntu Gnome".

Ubuntu Gnome looks like this:
[image: Ubuntu Gnome]

and the regular Ubuntu desktop Unity looks like this:
[image: Ubuntu Unity]